# Windows Phone 8.1 - Map Memory Leak

Tags: c#, dictionary, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8.1

I have some strange problem:

I have A and B pages. I navigate to page B (map contorl) and navigate back to page A. The result is that memory is not decreasing if i debug it or test with VS Performance and Diagnostic i will see memory increase each time I navigate on page B (only if cached it will increase one time, but will not decrease on navigation to page A)

Does anyone Know here how to get rid of map memory when i dont need it, and why GC wont collect it after some time?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: not yet, now i cache that view, but it still increasing memory